# Why doesn't npm install build the dependency?

Tags: npm

I forked a npm module git to my repo and listed it as a dependency in my project.

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "mobx": "git+https://github.com/myaccount/mobx"
}
```

this module will be downloaded in `node_modules` directory when I run `npm install` but it doesn't build. So I have to go to this directory and run `npm install` manually. Is there any way for me to configure it to build the dependnecy with `npm install` on the root of my project.

The `scripts` in package.json for the forked repo looks like:

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir dist",
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "prebuild": "npm run build",
    "preinstall": "npm run build"
  },
```

as you can see that the `dist` directory is not building so there is no `dist/index.js` file in this module.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just fixed that by upgrading `npm` to `5.6.0`.